# Diretiva do AngularJS bloqueando o ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Em uma aplicação angular, eu desenhei um pequeno sistema de abas e nesse sistema implementei uma diretiva para que sejam criados os eventos de `onclick` em cada uma das abas. basicamente o projeto ficou assim:

**stylesheet.css**

```
.-tabs{ width: 100%; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.-tabs nav { width: auto; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; overflow: hidden; }
.-tabs nav div{ height: 42px; flex: 1; display: block; width: auto; float: left; }
.-tabs nav div.active label{ background:#dadada; }
.-tabs nav div label{ width: 100%; height: 42px; padding:0 10px; line-height: 42px; 
                      text-align: center; display: block; background: #d2d2d2; 
                      cursor: pointer; text-overflow:ellipsis; 
}
.-tabs nav section{ display: none; }
```

**html**

```
<div class="-tabs" minha-diretiva>
    <nav>
        <div class="active">
            <label>tab 1</label>
            <section>{{foo}}</section>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>tab 2</label>
            <section>{{bar}}</section>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="-tabmain"></div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('minhaDiretiva', function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    var el = element[0],
    mi = el.querySelectorAll('label');
    for(var i=0; i<mi.length;i++){
      mi[i].addEventListener('click',function(){            
        var a = this.parentNode,
            b = a.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div'),
            c = el.querySelector('.-tabmain');
        for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
          b[i].className = b[i].className.replace('  ', ' ');
          b[i].className = b[i].className.replace('active', ' ');
        };
        c.innerHTML = this.parentNode.querySelector('section').innerHTML;
        a.className = a.className.concat('active');
      },false);
      if( mi[i].parentNode.className.indexOf('active') > -1 ){
        el.querySelector('.-tabmain').innerHTML = mi[i].parentNode.querySelector('section').innerHTML;
      };
    };
  })
;
```

Meu problema está ocorrendo sendo quando eu atualizo um dos ngModel's `foo` ou `bar` através de qualquer função no meu *controller* parece que os mesmos não são atualizados, ao contrário, o angular nem consegue ler os mesmos no meu bloco de código e o bloco mostrado continua sendo a máscara do ngModel. Alguém já viu algum erro semelhante? há alguma coisa que eu possa fazer na minha diretiva para que após seu processamento eu chame o angular para identificar estes ngModel's que estão dentro da mesma?

Comment: Dentro da diretiva você não vai conseguir acessar esses controllers, pelo menos não do jetio que está utilizando, o que você poderia fazer é utilizar o conceito de pai - filho, a direitiva é filha do controller acima, ou seja. para acessar o as variaveis acima, você poderia acessar $scope.$parent.foo ou $scope.$parent.bar.

Comment: Fala Leandro! Para facilitar a ajuda, teria como colocar o código envolvido no http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Entendi @RenanDegrandi, eu estava lendo um pouco sobre **$apply**, não tem como eu fazer com que após a diretiva ser instânciada eu execute um `$digest` ou um `$apply`?

Comment: você póde executar a função link, ficaria assim, .directive('minhaDiretiva', function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) { return {  link: function (scope, element, attrs){ ** o que executar aqui dentro já vai funcionar em um ciclo APPLY **  } }

Answer (score 0):

No lugar do seu código assim:

```
.directive('minhaDiretiva', function(scope, el, att, ctrl) {
    var el = element[0],
```

Por este:

```
.directive('minhaDiretiva', function(scope, element, att, ctrl) {
    var el = element[0],
```

Comment: airton, desculpe, essa correção já existe no meu código original, para postar aqui eu acabei reescrevendo em uma forma mais "leve" para não ficar cansativo o entendimento

Comment: Lendo novamente se as mascaras {{ foo }} e {{ bar }} estão aparecendo, parece que sua angular app não 'rodou' ou deu algum erro de sintaxe no código. Pode ser também que você precise compilar este novo html que sua diretiva criou para isso você precisa de um serviço extra $compile para que o angular identifique suas mascaras e execute o bindind do template com seu model, o $compile não é necessário em uma link function porém não custa verificar...